# Using ConcurrentBag correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Edit: Thank you, you made me realise that the code below is not working as I assumed, since somehow I thought that cbag works like a hashset. Sorry about it, you saved me some headache :)

the following function is the only function that can change _currentSetOfStepsProcessing. This function can be called from different threads. I am not sure if I understood correctly the use of a ConcurrentBag, so please let me know if in your opinion this can work. _stepsToDo datastructure is never modified once the process starts.

```
void OnStepDone(InitialiseNewUserBase obj)
    {
        var stepToDo = _stepsToDo[_currentSetOfStepsProcessing];

        stepToDo.TryTake(out obj);

        if (stepToDo.Count == 0) //can I assume it will enter here once per ConcurrentBag?
        {
            if (_currentSetOfStepsProcessing < _stepsToDo.Count - 1)
            {
                _currentSetOfStepsProcessing++;
            }
        }
    }

    List<ConcurrentBag<InitialiseNewUserBase>>      _stepsToDo = new List<ConcurrentBag<InitialiseNewUserBase>>();
    Action                                          _onFinish;
    int                                             _currentSetOfStepsProcessing;
```

Comment: This will take one item from the bag and then return, if there is an item. You'll probably want to loop and assign whatever you take from the bag to a local variable.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement a queue of queues, if so, `ConcurrentQueue` is probably the more appropriate data structure. Any reason you need the nested structure rather than a simple flat queue of all the work to do?

Comment: @Ian yes, I need level of priorities. The elements of the ConcurrentBag 0 must be processed before the elements of ConcurrentBag 1

Comment: @aevitas, I don't care about the return, I need the Count decreasing to 0. P.S.: sorry I misunderstood how cbag works, may bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `stepToDo.TryTake(out obj);` might fail, you don't handle that.
2. Why are you `out`-referencing the method argument? This simply overwrites the argument. Why take an argument if you throw it away? More likely, this is a misunderstanding of some kind.
3. `can I assume it will enter here once per ConcurrentBag` since access to the bag is apparently concurrent multiple accessing threads might see `0`. So yes, you need to handle that case better.

Probably, you should not make things so difficult and use `lock` in combination with non-concurrent data structures. This would only be a good idea if there was a high frequency of bag operations which seems unlikely.

What about this:

```
foreach (/*processing step*/) {
 Parallel.ForEach(/*item in the step*/, x => { ... });
}
```

Much simpler.

Comment: 1) as far as I understood, it should fails only if the key doesn't exist (it's not my case)


2) it's the way TryTake works. It confuses me as well, but it wants the key with the out parameters. The result must actually be the same of the input object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184(v=vs.110).aspx


3) I'll check that thanks

4) I am using a version of .Net that doesn't support Parallel

Comment: What key? CBag is not keyed. There is no input to Take. out means "cannot read, only write". Regarding 4, maybe use something equivalent or use some library. Much less awkward than managing all these collections.

Comment: oh! Thanks that was the missing part! Now I understand, the code is totally wrong then